# The most efficient method to find an element in Set

Tags: java, collections, set, treeset

I have the Person class:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private int id;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        return id == other.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return Integer.compare(id, o.id);
    }
}
```

And I have TreeSet of persons.
I need to implement method `findPersonById(int id)` in TreeSet.

I made it this way:

```
public Person find(int id) {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList(idTreeSet);
    Person pattern = new Person(id);
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(personList, pattern);
    return index < 0 ? null : personList.get(index);
}
```

Now the efficient of the find method is O(n) because it needs to copy all of elements from TreeSet to ArrayList.

But is there more efficient way to implement this method?

I don't need a Map. I'm interesed to resolve it without Maps.

Comment: Do you need to store things in TreeSets, as opposed to just using sorted ArrayLists all the time?

Comment: BTW: `new ArrayList<>(idTreeSet);` otherwise you lose type-safeness.

Comment: By using a TreeMap instead of a TreeSet.

Comment: A `TreeMap` where the key is the Id and value is the Person sounds much better suited to the problem.  Life is always harder after choosing the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `TreeSet` is a `NavigableSet`, you can use [`TreeSet.subSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet(E,boolean,E,boolean)), which leverages knowledge about the order of the elements to extract a range of elements as close as possible to the element you are interested in:

```
Person pattern = new Person(id);

return
    // Get the Persons between pattern (inclusive) and pattern (inclusive).
    // In other words: all the Persons with id equal to the input,
    // of which there are zero or one.
    idTreeSet.subSet(pattern, true, pattern, true).stream()
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: @Sweeper yes, because `tailSet` returns elements _greater than_ or equal to. You could potentially find the Person with the next-largest id, if there is no Person with the given id.

Comment: yes, it seems very nice

Comment: by the way, what's the efficient of subset method?

Comment: It's logarithmic.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are prepared to allocate a temporary `Person` object, you can do it like this:

```
public Person find(int id) {
    Person temp = new Person(id);
    Person candidate = idTreeSet.ceiling(temp);
    return temp.equals(candidate) ? candidate : null;
}
```

This is `O(logN)`.

Note that we only create one temporary object here.  If we use `tailSet` or `subSet` we will be creating at least second one; i.e. the `NavigableSet` returned by the `tailSet` or `subSet` call.  (Looking under the hood of the `TreeSet` implementation, it looks like more will be created.)

---

If you don't need the properties of a `TreeSet` then using a `HashMap<Integer, Person>` or a `HashSet<Person>` would give you `O(1)` lookup.  But in the latter case, you need change your `Person` class to satisfy the equals / hashCode contract.

Comment: I use `TreeSet`s so infrequently that I forget about all these methods. +1.

Comment: yes, it's good solution too, thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Person> personsById = new HashMap<>();
```

Would definitely be fastest, though *not Tree based*. A LinkedHashMap for order of insert would allow some order.

It is the more rugged solution.